Regular expression to extract monetary values from an invoice text
I have a regular expression:
\b[-+]?(?:\d{1,3}\.)(?:\d{3}\.)*(?:\d*) (Python) that matches numeric values in strings like this:
Amount: 12.234.55222 EUR
Some Text 123.222.22 maybe more text
1.245.455.2
22.34565 Could be at the beginning
It could be at the end of a string 21.1
221. It could be a number like this too (for US invoices, I saw a lot of different stuff)

Which is what I want.
But it also matches the first 2 parts of a date like this: 08.05.2023 
I know this is happening because of the first and the last group, but I don't know how to prevent that.
I only want to match values that stand by themselves.
 Can somebody point me in the right direction?
Edit:
I forgot to mention that I've tried it with a negative look behind, but that didn't work:
\b([-+]?(?:\d{1,3}\.)(?:\d{3}\.)*(?:\d*))(?!(?:\.d{4}))

Maybe I'm doing the look behind wrong?

Split on space and use ^([-+]?(?:\d{1,3}\.)(?:\d{3}\.)*(?:\d*))$? Otherwise, it'll become too expensive, if you have a long string. Are these monetary values 12.234.55222 or 221. ?

That is an excellent Idea, I like that. Thank you very much, I will provide some code when I'm done

Your requirements are not evident from the examples you wish to match and the one string you do not wish to match. If you precisely state in words the characteristics of strings that you wish to match the required regular expression will likely fall right out. Be sure to indicate whether you wish to match an entire string or part of a string if certain requirements are satisfied. For example, could the string be "The string 12.234.55222 is an unusual phone number" rather than just "12.234.5522".

@CarySwoveland I want to match all kinds of possible money-related strings. But I want to prevent falls positives that could occur if my regex also matches a date like this.
I have posted the solution to my problem with the help of user24714692

Note that (?!(?:\.d{4})), which is a negative lookahead, can be simplified to (?!\.d{4}). Also "...but that didn't work..." is vague. It's not clear if the Python regex was invalid or it didn't match a string that should have been matched or matched a string that shouldn't be matched.  Strive to be precise in all things coding.

With the idea of @user24714692 I've done it this way:
def float_check(text: str) -> bool:
    try:
        float(text)
        return True
    except ValueError:
            return False
        
def match_amount(amount: float, text: str) -> bool:
    pattern = r"^([-+]?(?:\d{1,3}\.)(?:\d{3}\.)*(?:\d*))$"
    # find all numbers, that match a pattern like i.e.: (123./,)*23

    # replace all comma, because the US is doing the numbers like this 291,234.23
    text = text.replace(",", ".")

    numbers = [
        pot_number for pot_number in text.split() if re.findall(pattern, pot_number)
    ]

    for number in numbers:
        # now replace all dots but the last one
        number = re.sub(r"\.(?=.*\.)", "", number)
        # and convert the numbers to float, and check if the number equals the given amount
        if float_check(number) and float(number) == amount:
            return True
    return False
    
print(match_amount(23.45, "some text with numbers here"))

Works pretty fine now, thank you very much.

I have assumed that the strings must follow one of the formats given by the six examples. For example, I have assumed that "12.234.55222" represents strings comprised of two digits, followed by a period, followed by three digits, followed by a period, followed by five digits.
You could match the regular expression
^[+-]?(?:\d\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d|\d{2}\.(?:\d{3}\.\d{5}|\d{6}\.\d|\d{2}\.\d)|\d{3}\.(?:\d{3}\.\d{2})?)$

Demo
I have written the expression at the link in extended, or free-spacing mode to make it easier to read and to be self-documenting.
If the examples can be parts of strings (rather than the entire string), replace ^ with two negative lookbehinds, (?<!.)(?<!\d), and replace $ with a negative lookahead, (?![.\d]).

Ah sorry, I should clarify the question a bit. The strings don't have to be at the end / beginning of a line. There could be something like this: Amount: 123.222.22 EUR.
But for the case I've presented it works fine. Edit: question more clear now, still thank you for your help

The last sentence of my answer explains how the regular exppression I have suggested should be modified to address your question as it reads now, after your edit. You can verify that by modifying the regex and test strings at the "Demo" link I gave.
